# Hole in interior wall, can't figure out what I'm looking at

Tags: drywall, mold, hole, patching-drywall

1994 home, hole in the wall of my hallway. Southern home with a crawl space. Not sure how the hole got there.

I haven't been able to come up with the right google search to understand what I'm looking at.

I'm concerned about the dark brown stuff, which is dry and hard. Behind the brown layer I can see (I assume) clean white drywall on the left there, and if I look directly into the hole I see some blank space and then a clean wood stud. The "brown" seems to be a very distinct layer of something on top of the drywall behind it, but I'm not sure.

I can't seem to find an example to understand... is this 2 layers of drywall? (drywall, brown stuff, drywall, paint?) Is the brown stuff a problem or indication of mold or something else?  (No mold issues in our crawl space, though we haven't lived here that long).

Thoughts on what I'm looking at? Thank you for the help.

[image]

Comment: Rusty corner beading.  Thin metal corners are use for corners of drywall.  A bit stronger than just tape and usually has a nice raise section to feather out the drywall mud.  Not sure what the extra is further along the wall.  Beads are usually just an inch or two.

Answer (score 2):

The brown stuff is rust.  How it got there is a mystery that you will have to help us figure out with more info.

The corner of the drywall is us done with a "corner bead".  That runs vertically from the floor to the ceiling. Some are PVC but yours is metal and somehow it got wet. Thus the rust.

It looks like there is drywall and corner bead over a stud in a corner. All that is normal.  Having it rust is not normal without some source of moisture.

Tell us more about where in the home the corner is and what may be over it and a possible determination can be made.